# How to use enlive's clone-for with an HTML template to remove dummy child elements

Tags: html, clojure, enlive

See [this google groups topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/enlive-clj/EJWSH5G7rH0)

Several people have expressed confusion with using `clone-for` to insert a list of dynamically generated elements into a template which includes several dummy elements. For example, maybe the template looks like this,

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

And we want to generate HTML like this,

```
<ul>
    <li>real</li>
    <li>data</li>
    <li>here</li>
    <li>wurdz</li>
</ul>
```

The naive thing to try is something like

```
(defsnippet my-snippet "my-template.html" [:ul] [items] 
    [[:li first-of-type]] (clone-for [ii items]
                             [:li] (content ii)))
```

But that leaves the 2nd through nth elements with the dummy data. How can we simply remove all the dummy elements and replace with real one?

Answer (score 5):

The solution I've been using is to do something like,

```
(defsnippet my-snippet "my-template.html" [:ul] [items]
  [[:li (html/but html/first-of-type)]] nil
  [[:li html/first-of-type]] (html/clone-for [ii items] ...))
```

Which deletes all the dummy nodes, and inserts new ones with my content.

Answer (score 4):

I think that a different approach could be something like this:

```
(defsnippet my-snippet "my-template.html" [:ul [:li (nth-of-type 1)]] [items] 
  [:li] (clone-for [ii items]
      [:li] (content ii)))

(deftemplate my-template "my-template.html"
  [items]
    [:ul] (content (my-snippet items)))
```

First, you define snippets with the specific elements that you want to clone with real data, then you can define a template and replace the contents of the elements where you want to put the snippets. This way you don't have to delete the dummy nodes.